# R - String Comparison To Recode Values of Another Variable

Tags: r, string, dataframe, variables, recode

I have an R data frame and I am trying to reassign cell values that are blank or incorect given if another column cell is a specific string. The data frame looks like this.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| PowerSec | SOUTH |
| AVPower | SOUTH |
| PowerSec | SOUTH |
|  | SOUTH |
| PowerSec | SOUTH |
| AVPower | MIDWEST |
| AVPower | MIDWEST |

I want to replace the missing data from column A with the proper name if column B contains the word "SOUTH". I tried this code below to no avail. I looked at some different uses of if and ifelse online, but I wanted to see the most simple and direct way possible.

if(df$B == "SOUTH"){replace(df$A, "PowerSec")}

I'm sorry if this is very simple or beginner stuff. I am in school and this is a side project I am working on. I am trying to automate and clean missing or incorrect data quickly based on conditions. I can do this by hand in Excel as the actual data set is not that large, but I want to learn more about R. So far in my classes we largely work with numbers rather than strings. Most of my string experience is in SAS. I would like to replace both blank spots and ones like AVPower, which should be PowerSec, in the second and fourth lines. I may not even need if/ifelse statements. I am open to any suggestions and it would help my learning process to see different approaches. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Naming your df power, and shortening South to S,  PowerSec to PS, you could change column A via `power$A <- ifelse(power$B == 'S', 'PS', power$A). It was useful for you to edit your question, next time something like `power <- data.frame(A= c('PS', 'AV', 'PS', '', 'PS', 'AV', 'AV'), B = c('S','S','S','S','S','MW', 'MW')), or dput(head(yourdata)) as things get more involved will help arriving at a reproducible example. Welcome again.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Most of my ifelse usage is in python or SAS. R is a little different but this helps me familiarize myself with the syntax better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the missing values where `B = 'South'` and if your missing value is denoted by blank (`''`).

```
df$A[df$A == '' & df$B == 'SOUTH'] <- 'PowerSec'
```

If the missing values are denoted by `NA`.

```
df$A[is.na(df$A) & df$B == 'SOUTH'] <- 'PowerSec'
```

If you want to replace `A` value to `'PowerSec'` for every `B = 'SOUTH'` irrespective if it is missing or not.

```
df$A[df$B %in% 'SOUTH'] <- 'PowerSec'
```

**data**

It is helpful if you share data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy (like below) using `dput(df)` .

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("PowerSec", "AVPower", "PowerSec", "", "PowerSec", 
"AVPower", "AVPower"), B = c("SOUTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", 
"SOUTH", "MIDWEST", "MIDWEST")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
df$A <- replace(df$A, df$A == '' & df$B == 'SOUTH', "PowerSec")
```